# Meaning of $F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, definition

I am self studying field theory.In field theory,if $K/F$ is a field extension,and $\alpha\in K$,we know that $F(\alpha)$ denotes the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $F(\alpha)$.We also know that $F(\alpha)=\{\frac{f(\alpha)}{g(\alpha)}:f,g\in F[x] $ and $g(\alpha)\neq 0\}$.But I have some doubt when it comes to several elements.For example $F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$.I know it is by definition the smallest subfield of $K$ containing the $3$ elements but can the set be written in fraction form i.e. $\frac{f(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)}{g(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)}$ where $f,g\in F[x_1,x_2,x_3]$.I am confused because I know that quotient fields of polynomial rings of the form $F[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ denoted by $F(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\{\frac{f(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{g(x_1,x_2,x_3)}:f,g\in F[x_1,x_2,x_3],g\neq 0\}$.So I thought that the field $F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ will also be fractions constructed by polynomials in $\alpha_i$'s but our instructor told us that it is not so.Can someone resolve my doubt?

Comment: The elements of $F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ are indeed of the form $f(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)/g(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$ where $f, g$ are polynomials with coefficients in $F$.

Comment: Sometimes easier to think of it as $F(\alpha_1)(\alpha_2)(\alpha_3).$ Also, that isn’t a quotient field, that is called a fraction field. A quotient field is something else (a quotient ring $R/I$ which is a field, where $I$ is a ring and $I$ is an ideal.)

Comment: In particular, $F(\alpha)$ is not, in general, isomorphic to  a quotient ring for $F[x],$ but it is a quotient ring of a sub-ring of the field $F(x),$ the fraction field of the integral domain $F[x].$

Comment: More generally, if $S\subset K,$ you can define $F[S]$ as the intersection of all fields $k$ with $F\subseteq k\subseteq K$ and $S\subseteq k.$ $F[\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n]=F[\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}].$ In general, $F[S]$ is the set of all ratios of polynomials in some finite subset of elements of $S.$ So if $S$ is infinite, the $F[S]$ is the union of all $F[S_0]$ where $S_0$ is a finite subset of $S.$